# Postgresql Select duplicate values repeating more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SELECT statement

```
SELECT user_id, cat_id, type_id, index_id FROM index_logs
```

I am looking to find out any index_id that exists more than once (duplicates) for a given group

```
"user_id, cat_id, and type_id"
```

So basically, index_id can only be duplicate if above group is different, but for that group of data there should not be any duplicates.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `group by ... having ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select user_id, cat_id, type_id, index_id
from t
group by user_id, cat_id, type_id, index_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: unsure why this is the approved answer as (a) the actual table name isn't correct and (b) it has multiple fields selected when OP asked specifically for "looking to find out any index_id that exists more than once"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    index_id 
FROM 
    index_logs 
GROUP BY 
    user_id
    , cat_id 
    , type_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(index_id) > 1
```